# why query all colum is way slower than query only id column in mysql high limit offset situation?

Tags: mysql

```
 1.   select * from inv_inventory_change limit 1000000,10

 2.   select id from inv_inventory_change limit 1000000,10
```

The first sql' timeconsumption is about 1.6s, the second sql timeconsumption is about 0.37s;

So the 2nd sql and 1st sql timeconsumption differential is about 1.27s;

I understand msyql will use covering index when only query indexed column, that is why 'select id' is faster;

**However, when i use in idlist sql below to execute, i found it only took about 0.2s which is much shorter than the differential(1.27s), which is confusing me;**

```
  select * from inv_inventory_change c where c.id in (1013712,1013713,1013714,1013715,1013716,1013717,1013718,1013719,1013720,1013721);
```

---

My key question is why the time differential is much bigger than the `where id in` sql;

The inv_inventory_change table has 2321211 records;

And i add 'order by id asc' on above sqls, the timeconsumption not change;

[EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUT4m.png)

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: And if you want some inkling of what is (and isn't) going on under the hood, then you have to provide the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Did you do the second query shortly after the first query? The row data may still be cached in memory, so it doesn't have to go to disk.

Comment: How many and what type of columns are there in inv_inventory_change table?

Answer (score 1):

The rule is very simple; your first query can be served without reading data from the disk/memory cache.

```
select id from inv_inventory_change limit 1000000,10
```

This can be directly served from the index table (B-Tree or its variant) without reading page information and other meta information.

```
select * from inv_inventory_change limit 1000000,10
```

This query will require two steps to fetch records. First, it will perform a query on the index table, which would be quick, but next, it needs to read page information for those records that will require disk io and storing in cache, etc. Since a LIMIT is applied, it will automatically sort for you depending on the default ORDER BY setting, most likely it will sort using the `id` field. Since you're selecting a large number of records it will use FileSort to sort records or something similar.

```
select * from inv_inventory_change c where c.id in (1013712,1013713,1013714,1013715,1013716,1013717,1013718,1013719,1013720,1013721);
```

This query would be served using a range scan on the index table and it can find the entry corresponding to `1013712` in `O(lon N)` time and it should be able the serve the query quickly.

You should also look at the number of records you're reading, e.g the query having `limit 1000000,10` will require many disk io due to a large number of entries whereas in the 3rd example it will read a handful number of pages.

Comment: The question is why there isn't the same time difference when he uses `WHERE id IN (...)`, even though it needs 2 steps.

Comment: The word 'default' is a little misleading in this context